# How to set custom community login page with aura to default login page?

Tags: community, login, redirect

I created custom community login page via aura. I accessed to my community login page such as https://mycommunity url/communityname/login, but this URL is go to community experience builder's login page.I did the setting of redirect url at Site setting, but can't redirect to custom community login page.How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this from the administration page within the Community Workspace.

[image]

For a custom Aura Component, I'd recommend just updating the standard Login Page in the Community Builder to use your login component instead of the standard.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I need to create custom login page, not the login component. Community builder has not settings to set the custom login page via aura.

Comment: The standard Login Page is just a page which holds a Standard Lightning Component, You can replace this component with a custom Aura component

Comment: I understand standard login page is just page but I need to create with SSO and customize design to custom login page and want to set custom login page to default login page. The standard login page can not freely customize content layout and social login component.

Comment: @WinMyintOo SSO shouldn't really have anything to do with the page. The fact is, that an aura component requires a page to act as a container, if the built in login page doesn't work, you can create a new page with a more satisfying layout and customization options and select "experience builder page" from the list above. Embed your compoent into this page and you're good to go. If this is not good enough for you then you need to do a VF page and embed your component onto that and select VF page from the list above. Regardless, this is the correct answer.

Comment: @gNerb Thanks for your reply. My new custom login page wasn't shown in the "experience builder page". Any ideas on this point?